# Porque cuando le pongo transform:translate a un div este sobrepone todo como si tuviera un z-index alto?, como lo puedo arreglar?

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]
Mi problema es que las imagenes del carusel tienen transform:translate y esta propiedad por alguna razon sobrepone a todos los elementos, tanto a mis modals con position absolite con z-index:10 y a mi header con z-index:5 y position fixed, que puedo hacer?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, por favor agrega código de lo que has intentado [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)